# Removing selection area from canvas when no layer is available or selected

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I am new to QGIS 3 and I can not figure out the way to remove the selection from empty canvas or with Google Maps layers selected this area can not be removed. I tried to remove it by selecting a layer but still not successful.

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify,What are the steps to reproduce it?

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations, you found a weird bug. Fortunately, it's easy to fix.

**Here's how I reproduced the issue:**

1. With a polygon vector layer in Edit mode, start digitizing a new feature. While actively digitizing a new feature, the new feature is displayed as a transparent red "rubberband."

   [image]
2. Without finishing creating the new feature, switch to another tool, such as "Pan Map."  When you switch to another tool in the middle of creating a new feature, the "add feature" tool is paused, and the rubberband stays on the map. (This is a useful feature that allows you to pan or zoom the map canvas, then switch back to the "add feature" tool and continue digitizing the feature.)

   [image]
3. Remove the vector layer from the project by right clicking on the layer name in the Layer panel > Remove Layer. (You wouldn't normally do this.)

   [image]

The rubberband remains visible on the map after its parent layer is removed. The rubberband becomes an orphan, unconnected from any layer. It can't be selected or deleted.

[image]

**Solution**: add a new temporary scratch layer to the map. The rubberband immediately becomes part of that layer. The "add feature" tool is automatically activated (if it's not, click on this tool to activate it). Right click on the canvas to finish creating the new feature. The rubberband disappears, and is replaced by a normal vector feature. You can now remove the scratch layer, and the new polygon will be deleted.

Interestingly, if you add a line layer instead of a polygon layer, the new feature becomes a line.

[image]

If you add a point layer instead of a polygon or line, the rubberband doesn't go away.

[image]