# What is orange Polygon in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I have this orange Polygon, which is not saved in any layer.

How can I get rid of this and where does it come from ?

I am new to GIS.

[image: Orange Line]

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @Rahma! Does it appear each time you load QGIS or when you open a project?

Comment: Hi ! It only happens with this project

Comment: Are you sure it's not an element of any of your layer ? Can u select this 'object' ? Does right-clicking on it give something ? when u zoom out the map does it appear 'entirely' or is it like something 'infinite' ?

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a "rubberband", which is a temporary shape that appears on your map when you use certain tools, including the `Measure` tool and the `Add Feature` tool. Usually the rubberband goes away when you stop using the tool, but sometimes they get "stuck" on your screen. For example, see [this recent question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/328694/81764) where an `Add Feature` rubberband got stuck on a QGIS project.

Based on the orange color, I would guess that's the Measure Area tool rubberband. Orange is the default color of the Measure tool.

[image]

To make it go away, enable the Measure tool (in the Attributes toolbar) and measure a new area. Then close the Measure tool. If that doesn't work, open the Measure tool again, click "new" to clear the old rubberband, and close the Measure tool without using it.

[image]

If the new rubberband persists after closing the tool, or this becomes a recurring problem, [make a bug report](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues).